# Explain DWORD use of DWORD in Serial Communication

Tags: c, serial-port, readfile

I am studing serial communication with win32 using C now. reading from serial port is given as below.

```
DWORD dwEventMask;
DWORD dwSize;

if(!SetCommMask(hSerial, EV_RXCHAR)){
    //Error handling
    printf("Error Setting Comm Mask \n");
}

if(WaitCommEvent(hSerial, &dwEventMask, NULL))
{
    unsigned char szBuf[1024];
    DWORD dwIncommingReadSize;

    do
    {
        if(ReadFile(hSerial, &szBuf, 1, &dwIncommingReadSize, NULL) != 0) {
            //Handle Error Condition
        }

        if(dwIncommingReadSize > 0)
        {
            dwSize += dwIncommingReadSize;
            sb.sputn(&szBuf, dwIncommingReadSize);
            printf("Reading from port \n");
        }
        else{
        //Handle Error Condition
        }
        printf("Reading data from port \n");
    } while(dwIncommingReadSize > 0);
}
else
{
        //Handle Error Condition
}
```

They have used DWORD dwIncommingReadSize for while condition  (while(dwIncommingReadSize > 0);.

Please explain how this condition is satifisfied. No modification can be seen for that.

Again please explain following part.

```
if(dwIncommingReadSize > 0)
{
    dwSize += dwIncommingReadSize;
    sb.sputn(&szBuf, dwIncommingReadSize);
    printf("Reading from port \n");
 }
```

Comment: This is not great code but we can't see the error handling.  Clearly *iff* there's an error then the total number of bytes read could be 0.  So it just keeps trying anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
if(ReadFile(hSerial, &szBuf, 1, &dwIncommingReadSize, NULL)
```

passes the *address* of `dwIncommingReadSize` (however badly spelt it may be) to the function so it can change it to whatever it wants.

It's similar to:

```
void fn (int *x) { *x = 42; }
:
int xyzzy = 1;
fn (&xyzzy);
// Here, xyzzy is now 42.
```

---

In terms of your second question, it's a little hard to tell without seeing more of the code, but it looks like it's simply increasing a "total size" variable for each block of data read in (plus whatever `sb.sputn` is supposed to do).

This is typical where a single read may not get all the data you want - you simply store what you got and then go back for more.

Comment: Internet needs to learn how to spell this word. This might help: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/incoming

Comment: do 　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　
    { 
       
    } while(dwIncommingReadSize > 0); 
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　Thank you for quick reply,　Please explain this do-while loop too..

Comment: @Kumaa: The loop runs at least once. It continues to run until the condition is false (ie, while `dwIncomingReadSize > 0`). As stated, that variable can be set in the call to `ReadFile`.